# SVG how to set max width for group

Tags: svg, barcode

I have some SVG elements grouped together in a `<g>` element (exactly the barcode 1D, PHP generates a barcode).

```
  <g
 style="fill:#000000;stroke:none"
 id="barcode1D"
 transform="matrix(1.2083333,0,0,0.8247805,62.027778,573.54235)">
<rect
   x="0"
   y="0"
   width="4"
   height="30"
   id="xyz" />
```

....

```
    <rect
   x="224"
   y="0"
   width="0"
   height="30"
   id="xyzn" /> </g>
```

The barcode is generated in various widths, lengths. How can I set the width permanently ?

Based on this example, I am asking for a hint. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SVG [`g` element does not have `width` and `height` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#GElement). Therefore, you can not set `height` and `width` on it.

You should use a `foreignObject` with a `svg` inside of it to do so.

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject id="G" width="300" height="200">
    <svg>
     <!-- Barcode here -->
     <rect fill="black" stroke-width="2" height="112" width="84" y="55" x="55" stroke="#000000"/>
     <circle fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"  cx="155" cy="65" id="svg_7" r="50"/>     
    </svg>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's the point of the foreignObject? An <svg> element has width and height.

Comment: Exactly. I need a solution (container) that scales the generated barcode always at the same width.

Comment: unfortunately, no ;/

Comment: @PiccoloTest you should add more info.

Comment: PHP generates barcode - random width. I need SVG to convert the embedded barcode to constant always width. Is it possible ? from SVG level